# Trying to unnest promises with mongoose queries

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I currently have a create method that creates a new adventure, saves it, then adds the resulting adventure's ID to a user. The only problem is, it has nested promises and I'm wondering if there's a way to prevent that. The code:

```
function create(req, res) {
  new Adventure(req.body)
    .save()
    .then(function (result) {
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        result.dm_id,
        { $push: { adventures: result._id }}
      )
        .exec()
        .catch(fail); // FIXME: nested promises :(
      res.status(200).send(result);
    })
    .catch(fail);
}
```

I think the catch here is that I need to send the response back with the adventure I created, rather than the user I add the adventure to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return the promise that (your code implies) is returned by .exec - then you should be able to do something like this

```
function create(req, res) {
    new Adventure(req.body)
    .save()
    .then(function (result) {
        var ret = User.findByIdAndUpdate(result.dm_id, { $push: { adventures: result._id }}).exec();
        res.status(200).send(result);
        return ret;
    })
    .catch(fail);
}
```

or

```
function create(req, res) {
    new Adventure(req.body)
    .save()
    .then(function (result) {
        res.status(200).send(result);
        return User.findByIdAndUpdate(result.dm_id, { $push: { adventures: result._id }}).exec();
    })
    .catch(fail);
}
```

not sure if it's "valid" to use `res.status` line before the `findByIdAndUpdate` line, so this second code block may be wrong

Comment: Thank you! You are in fact able to send a response (forgot to mention I'm using express) before returning a value, so the second block works just as well as the first.